# using System.Net; IPEndPoint not found

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I'm new to monodevelop and csharp litle experience in the past.

Trying to do this example:
http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=600009&referringTitle=KB

I get and error

> TestAsyncGet/Program.cs(32,32): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IPEndPoint' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? (CS0246) (TestAsyncGet)

Thank you for any help.

Have in references System.Net also is complaining about:

> Projects/TestAsyncGet/TestAsyncGet/Program.cs(13,13): Error CS0825: The contextual keyword `var' may only appear within a local variable declaration (CS0825) (TestAsyncGet)

**Running from the command line:**

> mono TestAsyncGet.exe  System.FormatException: Input string was not in
>   the correct format   at System.Int64.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at TestAsyncGet.Program.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

```
GetRequestMessage message = new GetRequestMessage(0,
                VersionCode.V1,
                new OctetString("stvtelco"),
                new List<Variable> {new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4"))});
    long ip = Int64.Parse("192.168.0.33");
            var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(ip), 161);

            message.BeginGetResponse(endpoint, new UserRegistry(), endpoint.GetSocket(), ar => {
                var response = message.EndGetResponse(ar);
                Console.WriteLine(response);
            }, null);
            Console.Read();
```

Comment: `IPEndPoint` should work as long as you have `using System.Net;` at the top of the file. Is your code exactly as the one in the sample? The other error indicates you also have some syntactic error in your code.

Comment: I'm now trying to run this code from the command line:
See above for details please.

Comment: `Int64.Parse("192.168.0.33")` doesn't make any sense. Just use `IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.33")` to get the `IPAddress`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are:

- building with the .NET 4.0 profile. That will select the `dmcs` compiler and will enable the `var` keyword syntax;
- have a reference to `System.dll` assembly in your project. This is where `System.Net` namespace resides on the *regular* framework (that's a bit different for Silverlight since it has a `System.Net.dll` assembly);
- have a `using System.Net;` at the top of your file.

With those conditions you should be able to compile this code correctly.

Comment: Was missing the reference for System in the references listed in Monodevelop.

Comment: `var` works since C# 3.0, so I think `gmcs` should be fine too. (I doubt anyone uses `mcs` anymore.)

Comment: right (var) and wrong (mcs). Mono's new compiler, that can target every versions of the framework, is also named `mcs` ;-)